# how to display the size of USB/SD peripherals in my batch?

Tags: usb, batch, size

I made a small batch file to display the size, name and id of USB sticks and SD cards connected to a PC for test purposes. I tried to use **`:~0,-9%`** to shorten the size displayed in bytes, this works well out of the loop for the last item, but I'm unable to include this expression inside the loop, if several peripherals are in use.
Can somebody help and explain?
Please note I'm new to batch programming.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:chkUSB
set $List=
set $nom=
set $size=
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2-4 delims=," %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get deviceid^,Size^,VolumeName^ /format:csv^') do (
    set "$List=!$List! %%a" & set "$size=!$size! %%b" & set "$nom=!$nom! %%c"
)
::Displaying USB/SD drives
rem set $size=!$size:~0,-9! 
echo.
echo Disque USB : !$List!        
echo nom disque : !$nom%!
echo taille dsk : !$size%!
```

Comment: Hello, if you are beginning to script and don't have to do it in batch for some unknown reason then I recommend learning PowerShell instead. Batch is outdated, has messy syntax and is harder to learn.

Comment: The [The WMIC tool is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features)  The tool is superseded by [Windows PowerShell for WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/07-working-with-wmi)

Comment: I'm a programmer who coded in lots of languages and I can't comprehend batch syntax very often, although I'd be able to write some basic scripts, but I'd do it in PowerShell few times faster. Many answers on here/SO that use PowerShell are understood instantly by me, but batch can be quite hard and annoying to read at times. The "crazy syntax" here is kind of a proof too.

Comment: I mostly agree with the first comment made by @Destroy666 in most regards.  Batch doesn't have to be messy or hard to learn.. but it indeed isn't where the future is going.  There is nothing wrong with batch (I am a master) and there is nothing wrong with WMIC (we use it internally at MS a lot) but I highly suggest (judging by your syntax) that you skip batch and go straight for powershell or another language.  Batch is a dying language and learning it will not help you in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I'll post a quick alternative for PowerShell, to compare and also because googling yielded mostly outdated deprecated solutions, maybe more people will find it useful:

```
Get-Volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq "Removable" } | Select DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, @{ label="Size"; expression={ $_.Size -replace ".{9}$" } }
```

Step by step explantation:

- `Get-Volume` - gets all available volumes
- `|` - pipes, which pass the last results to next functions
- `? { $_.DriveType -eq "Removable" }` - checks if `DriveType` property of volumes equals `Removable`. `?` is shorthand for `Where-Object` filtering function.
- `Select DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel` - selects these 2 properties of volumes to be displayed in output
- `@{ label="Size"; expression={ $_.Size -replace ".{9}$" } }` - ... and 3rd custom expression one labelled as `Size` which is that property with last 9 chars removed, defined in a `HashTable`. Could also use e.g. `$_.Size / 1GB` to just display in specific unit.

With your own labels and usage of vars:

```
$letter = @{ label="Disque USB"; expression={ $_.DriveLetter } }
$name = @{ label="Nom disque"; expression={ $_.FileSystemLabel } }
$size = @{ label="Taille dsk"; expression={ $_.Size -replace ".{9}$" } }
Get-Volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq "Removable" } | Select $letter, $name, $size
```

Comment: No down-votes here.. this is a good alternative to what OP asked for!  Great answer.  One thing I would add is deprecated doesn't mean DON'T USE.. we use all sorts of deprecated stuff internally at MS.  Funny too.. the "deprecated" stuff keeps getting updated despite the deprecated label.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `get` one `item` at a time, define one `item` at a time, append one `value` to a `variable` at a time?

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_get=DeviceID,VolumeName,Size"
for %%i in =;(!_get!)do set _%%~i=1<nul

for %%G in =;(!_get!)do for /f ^usebackq^tokens^=^4^delims^=^<^> %%i in =;(`
   wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get %%~G /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"`
   )do if not defined _%%G =;(set "_%%~G=%%~i")else set "_%%~G=!_%%~G! %%~i"
   
set "_sSize=" & for %%i in (!_Size!)do if not defined _sSize =;(
       call set "_sSize=%%~i" && call set "_sSize=!_sSize:~0,-9!"
     );= else =;(
       call set "_sSize=!_sSize! %%~i" && call set "_sSize=!_sSize:~0,-9!"
     );=

rem./::Displaying USB/SD drives & echo/
echo/Disque USB: !_DeviceID!      
echo/nom disque: !_VolumeName!
echo/taille dsk: !_sSize!

endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

**1.** Define the items that will be used for get the values in loop in `wmic` command and also use them for variable names and relevant concatenation:

```bat
set "_get=DeviceID,VolumeName,Size"
```

---

**2.** Remove each pre-existing if/non-existing variable/value, which is similar to yours below but in a single line/loop:

```bat
set $List=
set $nom=
set $size=
for %%i in =;(!_get!)do set _%%~i=1<nul

:: or... 
for %%i in =;(DeviceID,VolumeName,Size)do set _%%~i=1<nul
```

---

**3.** Get in an initial loop the name of the item and use it to define a variable if it is not defined, if it is defined, use the loop variable `_%%G` to concatenate with the new value (`!_%%G! + %%i`) obtained from each driver/property.

```bat
for %%G in =;(!_get!)do for /f ^usebackq^tokens^=^4^delims^=^<^>^ %%i in =;(`
   wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get %%~G /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"`
   )do if not defined _%%G =;(set "_%%G=%%~i")else set "_%%~G=!_%%~G! %%~i"
```

- **Obs.:** What the 1st **`%%G`** and 2nd **`%%i`** in **`for`** loops are doing together is best visualized this way:

```bat
for %%G in =;(DeviceID)do for /f ^usebackq^tokens^=^4^delims^=^<^> %%i in =;(`
   wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get DeviceID /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"`
   )do if not defined _DeviceID =;(set "_DeviceID=%%~i")else set "_DeviceID=!_DeviceID! %%~i"
   
for %%G in =;(VolumeName)do for /f ^usebackq^tokens^=^4^delims^=^<^> %%i in =;(`
   wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get VolumeName /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"`
   )do if not defined _VolumeName =;(set "_VolumeName=%%~i")else set "_VolumeName=!_VolumeName! %%~i"
   
for %%G in =;(Size)do for /f ^usebackq^tokens^=^4^delims^=^<^> %%i in =;(`
   wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get Size /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"`
   )do if not defined _Size =;(set "_Size=%%~i")else set "_Size=!_Size! %%~i"
```

---

**4.**  Now I'm removing the variable/value `_sSize` (*sort Size*) if/not existing/defined, and looping for using the values using values already defined in `!_Size!` (`7725907968 7794573312`) and separated by space *`(sizeDrive1 SizeDrive2)`* and directly defined `_sSize` with initial value of the loop in `%%i` if not defined it, and concatenating with the current value `%%i` if already defined, but already counting the string removing the last 9 characters when defining it in `call set _sSize=!_sSize:~-9!`:

---

## PowerShell

A **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** alternative demonstrating a similar attempt to yours would look something like this:

```bat
Rv -Na dev,nam,size 2>$null
Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk -f "Drivetype=2" | Select 'DeviceID','VolumeName','Size' | ? {
  $dev=$dev+' '+$_.DeviceID; $nam=$nam+' '+$_.VolumeName; $size=$size+' '+[math]::round($_.Size/1GB) }

Write "`nDisque USB :$dev`nnom disque :$nam`ntaille dsk :$size"
```

- Output:

```bat
Disque USB : F: G:
nom disque : SDCARDX USBDRV
taille dsk : 7 7
```

---

- The same code but without the use of aliases, it would be:

```bat
# Remove variables ​​from previous runs
Remove-Variable -Name dev,nam,size 

# PS1 "wmic" command in loop to get and cancatenate values ​​for
Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk -f "Drivetype=2" | Select-Object 'DeviceID','VolumeName','Size' | Foreach-Object {

# Define and loop concatenate values ​​to your variables
     $dev=$dev+' '+$_.DeviceID; $nam=$nam+' '+$_.VolumeName; $size=$size+' '+[math]::round($_.Size/1GB) }

# Print on screen your sorted values line by line (`n == new line)
Write-Output "`nDisque USB :$dev`nnom disque :$nam`ntaille dsk :$size"
```

---

**[`CMD /commands /syntaxes /help`](https://ss64.com/nt/)**

**[`PS1 -commands -syntaxes -help`](https://ss64.com/ps/)**

---

**Obs.:** The **[suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1781316/969781)** to use powershell by the operator **[Destroy666](https://superuser.com/users/1145698/destroy666)** is welcome, but the current suggestions do not reproduce the output the output in a close/similar way to your attempt, so in addition to the code, you have a new alternative to compose the output too:

- Current **[Destroy666](https://superuser.com/users/1145698/destroy666)** suggestion #1 code:

```bat
PS G:\> Get-Volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq "Removable" } | Select DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, @{ label="Size"; expression={ $_.Size -replace ".{9}$" } }
```

- Current **[Destroy666](https://superuser.com/users/1145698/destroy666)** suggestion #1 output:

```bat
DriveLetter FileSystemLabel Size
----------- --------------- ----
          G USBDRV          7   
          F SDCARDX         7
```

- Current **[Destroy666](https://superuser.com/users/1145698/destroy666)** suggestion #2 code:

```bat
$letter = @{ label="Disque USB"; expression={ $_.DriveLetter } }
$name = @{ label="Nom disque"; expression={ $_.FileSystemLabel } }
$size = @{ label="Taille dsk"; expression={ $_.Size -replace ".{9}$" } }
Get-Volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq "Removable" } | Select $letter, $name, $size
```

- Current **[Destroy666](https://superuser.com/users/1145698/destroy666)** suggestion #2 Output:

```bat
Disque USB Nom disque Taille dsk
---------- ---------- ----------
         G USBDRV     7         
         F SDCARDX    7
```

---

**Obs.:** So as the environment has become receptive to PowerShell, I'm showing you how it's possible to use wmic in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** and at the same time proposing to use code similar to your attempts and get output that is more faithful to what you posted in the question, that's all. I understand that now you have more than one option to try **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**, I gave you one and the Destroy666 operator gave you 2 code/options.

---

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions ! I will learn a lot of trying to understand every bit of each reply...This is part of some automated testing of donated laptops to schools.
FYI I started IT with first IBM PC some 40 years ago and some small batch too...This explains that, but why not learn more with Powershell ?

Comment: I like PowerShell and respond eventually when there is a receptive environment for it. But I also respect the flagged tag and respond preferentially/priority in the tag. I'm not a militant, I don't keep suggesting powershell because many already do and I avoid being repetitive about it, tiring. Only that.

Comment: I use and learn focusing on the need of the moment, if I'm going to answer you, I learn by trying, and I find it easily for that, you can test and see for yourself, there is no PowerShell answer gap, everything has an explanation and demonstration of the target tasks. I find PowerShell more feature rich and faster at file manipulation (read/write) than cmd.exe, as the name already says **Power** + **Shell**

Comment: I've added some explanations for the code in **`bat`** and notes about hints in **`ps1`**